# PostgreSQL: How to get all records that doesn't have history tagged

Tags: postgresql

Need help on this..

I want to get all records that not being tagged for particular remarks.

What i have is:

**Table_1**

```
` Records         Status`
  ABCDE01         Opened
  ABCDE02         Done
  ABCDE03         Transferred
```

**Table_2**

```
` Records         History_Status           Date` 
  ABCDE01         Received                 2017-09-01
  ABCDE01         Opened                   2017-09-02

  ABCDE02         Received                 2017-09-01
  ABCDE02         Opened                   2017-09-02
  ABCDE02         For Processing           2017-09-03 ----- MISSING DATA
  ABCDE02         Transferred              2017-09-03
  ABCDE02         Done                     2017-09-03

  ABCDE03         Received                 2017-09-01
  ABCDE03         Opened                   2017-09-02
  ABCDE03         For Processing           2017-09-03
  ABCDE03         Transferred              2017-09-03
```

I want to get all the records that already tagged as Transferred and Done BUT NOT had "For Processing" History Status.

Table_1 captured the last status.

Table_2 captured all status as its log.

Someone could help me please.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not test this, but it should get all records that had a status `Transferred` but never had a status `For Processing`:

```
SELECT records
FROM table_1
   JOIN table_2 USING (records)
WHERE table_2.history_status = 'Transferred'
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM table_2 x
                  WHERE x.records = table_1.records
                    AND x.history_status = 'For Processing'
                 );
```

Comment: i'll try this one. ill update once done. thank you! ^_^